# Is it possible to fix a full memory dump so that running .imgscan /l will no longer be required?

Tags: windbg

For some reason I have started receiving dumps from production that require running `.imgscan /l` first.

Now I tend to run small queries against the dump using CDB invoked from a powershell script. However, running `.imgscan /l` every time takes considerable amount of time.

Is it possible to fix the dump in a way that renders `.imgscan /l` unnecessary?

P.S.

I think there is another problem with the need to run `.imgscan /l` - DebugDiag does not seem to understand such dumps.

Comment: Just a random thought: have you tried `.imgscan /l` and then save the dump again with `.dump /ma`?

Comment: Nope, never thought of this. Let me try. It did not occur to me that I can redump the dump.

Comment: i just did  .shell -ci ".echotime;.imgscan /l; .echotime "  grep -i UTC and it seems windbg takes about 2 milliseconds to process one module  40 milliseconds for 21 modules 0:000> .shell -ci ".echotime;.imgscan /l; .echotime "  grep -i UTC
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Sun Sep  4 03:59:18.243 2016 
Debugger (not debuggee) time: Sun Sep  4 03:59:18.283 2016 

0:000> .shell -ci ".echotime;.imgscan /l; .echotime "  grep -c MZ
21 what considerable amount of time means in your post ??

Comment: It depends on the dump, I think. I have a dump where `.imgscan /l` returns almost right away and another one where it takes about a minute. The latter dump does not show it has .NET dlls until `.imgscan /l` is run. I do not understand how it works,

Comment: @ThomasWeller - reviving the thread :-). Please, arrange your comment as an answer. I would like to comment on it since I now have some unexpected results for this procedure 6 years later using the latest WinDbg app.

Comment: Okay, as you wish... I don't know if that helps with your new questions/comments, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `.imgscan /l` has found the headers and assigned them to modules, `.dump /ma file.dmp` seems to write these information into a new dump file, making `.imgscan` unnecessary when examining the new dump file.

Comment: Could you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71339466/the-dump-ma-command-produces-a-dump-which-generates-a-lot-of-warnings-when-loa ? Thank you.