# What is the reason for failing to write a full memory minidump from within another minidump?

Tags: windbg

I was analysing a full memory minidump (31GB) and had to run **.imgscan /l** to fix the module references.

Now I am trying to save it (following the advice given here - [Is it possible to fix a full memory dump so that running .imgscan /l will no longer be required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39300224/is-it-possible-to-fix-a-full-memory-dump-so-that-running-imgscan-l-will-no-lon)) and here is the result:

```
0:000> .dump /ma "d:\tmp\cantestr52 - 06-09-2017\1.dmp"
Creating d:\tmp\cantestr52 - 06-09-2017\1.dmp - mini user dump
WARNING: Thread 1d8 context retrieval failure during dump writing, Win32 error 0n31
WARNING: Teb 146 pointer is NULL - defaulting to 00000000`7ffde000
WARNING: 00000000`7ffde000 does not appear to be a TEB
GenAllocateThreadObject.GetTebInfo(0x1d8) failed, 0x80004002
GenInvokeEnumStackProviders(mscordacwks.dll) failed, 0x8007007e
GenInvokeEnumStackProviders(mscordacwks.dll) failed, 0x8007007e
QuerySystemMemoryInformation failed, 0x80004001
QueryProcessVmCounters failed, 0x80004001
WriteFullMemory.Memory.Read(0x9788090000, 0x2000) failed 0x80004002, ABORT.
Dump creation failed, HRESULT 0x80004002
    "No such interface supported"
```

What is wrong?

**EDIT 1**

Here is the output of the version command:

```
0:000> version
Windows 8.1 Version 9600 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: Server, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
6.3.9600.18217 (winblue_ltsb.160124-0053)
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Fri Jun  9 03:03:19.000 2017 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 25 days 6:23:06.206
Process Uptime: 16 days 12:01:43.000
  Kernel time: 4 days 7:59:50.000
  User time: 2 days 17:49:40.000
Full memory user mini dump: D:\tmp\cantestr52 - 06-09-2017\Quartz.Server.DMP

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.15063.468 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

command line: '"E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\windbg.exe" '  Debugger Process 0x2750 
dbgeng:  image 10.0.15063.468, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbgeng.dll]
dbghelp: image 10.0.15063.468, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbghelp.dll]
        DIA version: 24610
Extension DLL search Path:
    E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\arcade;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\pri;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Dbg\EngineExtensions;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools\;%BPADir%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;E:\utils\LINQPad4;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;D:\Anaconda;D:\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;E:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\pg95\bin;E:\Program Files\Git\cmd;E:\Program Files\nodejs\;E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;E:\Utils;c:\dayforce\DayforceDEV\Utils;C:\Program Files\nodejs;c:\Program Files\WinRAR;c:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonEE9.6N\bin;C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Roaming\npm
Extension DLL chain:
    dbghelp: image 10.0.15063.468, API 10.0.6, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbghelp.dll]
    ext: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\ext.dll]
    exts: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP\exts.dll]
    uext: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\uext.dll]
    ntsdexts: image 10.0.15063.468, API 1.0.0, built Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
        [path: E:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP\ntsdexts.dll]
```

Comment: which windbg version do you use?

Comment: 10.0.14321.1024. I think it is a dump specific issue, because usually it works.

Comment: this is the TH1 version of the SDK from 2015. try TH2 or the latest RS2 (Creators Update 15063.400 - SDK)

Comment: I tried with the most recent WinDbg and get the same result.

Comment: ok, next time set Windows to generate an [ActiveMemory dump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/active-memory-dump) if you use Windows 10. "Active Memory Dump is similar to a Complete Memory Dump, but it filters out pages that are not likely to be relevant to troubleshooting problems on the host machine. **Because of this filtering, it is typically significantly smaller than a complete memory dump**" so try this in future