# The .dump /ma command produces a dump which generates a lot of warnings when loaded and worked on - how to fix?

Tags: windbg

Having a crash dump open

```
0:000> ||
.  0 Full memory user mini dump: c:\temp\dump\0.dmp
```

I [fix some images using `.imgscan`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39300224/is-it-possible-to-fix-a-full-memory-dump-so-that-running-imgscan-l-will-no-lon) and re-dump into a new file:

```
0:000> .dump /ma c:\temp\dump\1.dmp
Creating c:\temp\dump\1.dmp - mini user dump
GenInvokeEnumStackProviders(mscordacwks.dll) failed, 0x8007007e
GenInvokeEnumStackProviders(mscordacwks.dll) failed, 0x8007007e
QuerySystemMemoryInformation failed, 0x80004001
QueryProcessVmCounters failed, 0x80004001
Dump successfully written
```

I assume the failure messages can be ignored.

Now I close the debugger, reopen and load the new dump. The output is thrashed with gazillion of these messages right away:

```
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
```

Here is the beginning:

```
Process Uptime: 0 days 8:26:24.000
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
....
Loading unloaded module list
.........
This dump file has a breakpoint exception stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n1392
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
No flat address for current instruction
 ??              ???

Loading Dump File [C:\Temp\dump\1.DMP]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570

Loading Dump File [C:\Temp\dump\1.DMP]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get program counter
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n1392
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n1392
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
```

Here is how running a command looks like:

```
||2:0:000> .load c:\utils\sosex\64\sosex.dll
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n1392
```

And another command:

```
|2:0:000> .time
Debug session time: Wed Feb 23 14:29:27.000 2022 (UTC - 5:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 22:15:39.839
Process Uptime: 0 days 8:26:24.000
  Kernel time: 0 days 3:08:40.000
  User time: 1 days 2:53:06.000
Failed validating the extended context size for the thread 1204: 
GetContextState failed, 0x80070570
Unable to get current machine context, Win32 error 0n1392
```

So even the most innocent command results in these messages.

Why does it happen? How it can be fixed?

Comment: It seems you have a dump with .NET. Did something very bad happen (like FatalExecutionEngineException). Why do we see `||2:0:000>`? Did you open multiple dumps or attach to multiple processes?

Comment: Not at all. I do not know why it reports it this way. Reopened the debugger and it does not show the `| |2` prefix anymore. But the warning messages are still there.

Comment: Note that I can explore the original dump, it is the saved dump that is problematic.

Comment: Okay, that information is missing in the question. Originally you are not attached to a process but you are debugging a crash dump, which you then dump again. This seems to be reproducible BTW. I just did that for an arbitrary .NET crash dump I had available.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Only I am surprised it is reproducible. This procedure used to work, I thought something is wrong with my particular crash dump, but now it sounds like a problem with windbg.